# Lua - Concatinate several arguments passed into a function, until condition is met, then pass string to next function

Tags: function, lua, arguments

pvMessage is sent from another function, the message often comes in a few parts almost instantly.  I am looking to store the pvMessages and concatinate the message to the last.  Therefore a master string is created with all parts.

```
Example.
pvMessage #1 = thisispart1msg
pvMessage #2 = now part two is being received
pvMessage #3 = Part 3

MasterMessage = thisispart1msgnow part two is being receivedPart 3
```

I have tried several attempts at solving this issue.  The storing of the message outside the function is proving harder then I though, I keep overwriting the previous message.

```
    function ProcessClientMessage( pvMessage ) 
         if StartMessage == "" then
            StartMessage = pvMessage                
            pvMessage = ""
         end

         if pvMessage ~= "" then
             if MiddleMessage == "" then
                MiddleMessage = pvMessage
                pvMessage = StartMessage .. MiddleMessage
                pvMessage = ""
             end
          end

         if pvMessage ~= "" then
            if EndMessage == "" then
                EndMessage = pvMessage
                pvMessage = StartMessage .. MiddleMessage .. EndMessage
                pvMessage = ""
             end
         end

         if pvMessage ~= "" then
            ProcessClientMessageReset()
         end 
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are always three parts that you want to concatenate, something like this may work:

```
local buffer = {}
local function ProcessClientMessage(pvMessage) 
  if #buffer < 3 then
    table.insert(buffer, pvMessage)
  else
    --ProcessClientMessageReset(table.concat(buffer, ""))
    print(table.concat(buffer, ""))
    buffer = {}
  end
end
ProcessClientMessage("thisispart1msg")
ProcessClientMessage("now part two is being received")
ProcessClientMessage("Part 3")

ProcessClientMessage("more thisispart1msg")
ProcessClientMessage("some now part two is being received")
ProcessClientMessage("Part 4")
```

This should print:

```
thisispart1msgnow part two is being receivedPart 3
more thisispart1msgsome now part two is being receivedPart 4
```

Comment: As I see your method, I realize there are other factors to consider. What if I dont know how many items I am expecting? It shouldnt be more then 4, however what happens if its 1,2,3. I do know that everything should come almost at once so a timer could be used to opt out, such as 1000 ms. The other option to opt out, I know three difference key phrases that must be present, ie "Clip%=", "Next%=" and "Previous%=". And if 3 statements are not present and time has elapsed, clear all from memory. Wait for next communication. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no reliable way to do this based on a time interval. You can set up a signal, but it can only be done in a system-dependent way. I think if you can describe *why* you are trying to do this, maybe we can suggest a better option, as it seems to be a case of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I am receiving messages from a TCP client.  There are three messages that come all at once as a single string, but often are broken apart due to packets, transmission, etc. therefore need to be reassembled into the master stream.    The three identifiers "Clip%=", "Next%=" and "Previous%=", need to be present in the master string, it requires each identifier to be present.  
I am trying to solve for "what happens if" an identifier isnt present, therefore the master message isnt complete.  I need to either build the valid substrings based on complete identifiers, or dump the master string.

Comment: I think the best way would be to either send the length or send the messages with line terminators (CR/LF) to properly decode on the receiving side.

Answer (score 0):

This problem also be solved with coroutines:

```lua
local function consumer(consume)
   print(consume()..consume()..consume())
   return consumer(consume)
end

local process = coroutine.wrap(consumer)
process(coroutine.yield)

process('foo')
process('bar')
process('baz')

process('hello')
process('world')
process('test')
```

---

EDIT: As Egor pointed out, the order of evaluation isn't technically defined (although it's left to right in every Lua implementation I'm aware of) so here's an alternative that would work even if your interpreter was doing `gcc -O3`-like optimizations:

```lua
local function consumer(consume)
   local a = consume()
   local b = consume()
   local c = consume()
   print(a .. b .. c)
   return consumer(consume)
end
```

Comment: Lua doesn't guarantee that in expression `f1()..f2()` the function `f1` would be called first and `f2` second.  Although it is true for the current implementation.

Comment: As I see your method, I realize there are other factors to consider.  What if I dont know how many items I am expecting?  It shouldnt be more then 4, however what happens if its 1,2,3.  I do know that everything should come almost at once so a timer could be used to opt out, such as 1000 ms.  The other option to opt out, I know three difference key phrases that must be present, ie "Clip%=", "Next%=" and "Previous%=".    And if 3 statements are not present and time has elapsed, clear all from memory.  Wait for next communication.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the "or" assignment to simplify initialization of the global variable and then concatenate the string to the result. Consider:

```
function ProcessClientMessage(msg)
    msg_global_ = (msg_global_ or "")..msg
    print(msg_global_) -- Just for debug purposes so we can print each step
end

do
    ProcessClientMessage("thisispart1msg")
    ProcessClientMessage("now part two is being received")
    ProcessClientMessage("Part 3")
end
```

The variable `msg_global_` contains the string being built. If it has not been added too yet, then it will be nil. In this case the `or ""` will be executed and default the string empty.

We then simply append the string `msg`.

The output looks like:

```
thisispart1msg
thisispart1msgnow part two is being received
thisispart1msgnow part two is being receivedPart 3
```

When you actually process the message, just set the global variable to nil and you are good to go again.